# How healthy is our stack exchange compared to others?

Tags: discussion, statistics

For October 2015

Are there statistics available telling us whether we have more or less number of unanswered questions compared to other stack exchanges, and is there a metric available that ascertains whether our stack exchange is healthy or unhealthy in any regards?

Answer (score 30):

```
Stack Overflow
--------------

Questions  Accepted   >= 1 answers  Closed (Ex Deleted)
10386638   5819260    9148900       443261
```

Here, 56% of questions have an accepted answer and 88% have 1 or more answer (i.e. 12% have no answers). 4% are closed.

```
Ask Ubuntu
----------

Questions  Accepted   >= 1 answers  Closed (Ex Deleted)
204114     69534      162546        27566
```

Here 34% of questions have an accepted answer and 80% have one or more answer (i.e. 20% have no answers). 14% are closed.

```
Unix and Linux
--------------

Questions  Accepted   >= 1 answers  Closed
75899      38258      64049         4988
```

Here 50% of questions have an accepted answer and 84% have one or more answer (i.e. 16% have no answers). 7% are closed.

My pronouns are He / Him

Comment: If you want any other metrics, I'm happy to get them for you.

Comment: You might want to add number of closed questions to it.

Comment: @muru we have a lot of closed questions by the look of it.

Comment: I find it ironic that the answer to this question wasn't accepted.

Comment: The measures Area51 uses would be more useful than the raw values you show, in my opinion.  In particular, the percentage answered which discounts 0-score unaccepted answers. (That's the normal unanswered definition on SE.)

Comment: @otus lovely idea. Unfortunately, the stats are for the end of beta: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/7716/ubuntu

Comment: I'm also a member of the Writers Q/A, and that's still a "Beta" after several years, so this one is doing a lot better than that one is (although I'm quite happy with Writers as it is.)